# Why DispacherTimer.Tick event occurs two times?

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatchertimer

I use DispacherTimer to auto-save a file. The code is like the following:

```
void beginAutoSave()
{
    _autoSaveDispacherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    _autoSaveDispacherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    _autoSaveDispacherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(onAutoSaveTick);
    _autoSaveDispacherTimer.Start();
}

void onAutoSaveTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I save the file with a randomly generated file name
}
```

I call *beginAutoSave()* just once. The problem is that in each Tick event, two different files are being saved. In other words, *onAutoSaveTick(...)* method is called twice. The call stack seems to be the same in both calls. Where is my mistake?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you *absolutely sure* `beginAutoSave` is only executing once? What happens if you put a breakpoint in there? Can you reproduce this in a short but complete program?

Comment: Where's the code where you're calling `beginAutoSave()`?

Comment: Wow, you guess is right. It is executing twice, although I don't know why!!! Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

`onAutoSaveTick` will be called `after every one minute`. You need to `stop explicitly` timer if you want to execute it once.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.tick) documentation -

> The Tick event fires after the time specified in Interval has elapsed.
>   Tick continues firing at the same Interval until the Stop method is
>   called.

Do this in tick handler itself:

```
void onAutoSaveTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I save the file with a randomly generated file name
    _autoSaveDispacherTimer.Stop();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vats. Jon is right. It was a stupid mistake. I was executing beginAutoSave() method twice.